# sqlite3.OperationalError: near " ": syntax error . I think our syntax is correct ,but it always shows me this error

Tags: database, sqlite, python-3.7

we want to use  placeholders to solve the problem we need to input the table name that we don't know.
But it always shows me syntax error .

we have try any  placeholders method.
and ac is a variable

```
import sqlite3
with sqlite3.connect(f'{ac}.db') as conn:
      c = conn.cursor()
      c.execute(f"select name from {ac}")
```

```
    c.execute(f"select name from {ac}")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near " ": syntax error
```

I expect we can input the  placeholders to instead the real table name .
But it seems happens some syntax error.

Comment: Please indent the code using code formatter. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Please also include the complete error traceback. Which version of Python are you using? (f strings were introduced in Python 3.6, could you be using an older version?)

Comment: Just for the record - your code as it is, is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Use placeholders in your queries instead. 

More information https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a redundant space between the `f` and `'{ac}.db'`

```
import sqlite3
with sqlite3.connect(f'{ac}.db') as conn:
      c = conn.cursor()
      c.execute(f"select name from {ac}")
```

Comment: We have changed it ,but problem still exists.